# How to achieve the spiderify behaviour while rendering markers which has same coordinates in maplibre-gl?

Tags: maplibre-gl

When I'm trying to render the markers which has same coordinates, it overlaps with one another and the markers are not visible while zooming in and out.

How can I achieve that spiderify behaviour with maplibre-gl?.

I saw there is possibility in mapbox-gl with extention but not for maplibre-gl.